# Make Error Messages In Android Code

Tags: android, eclipse, message, alert

I' am making an app that connects to the database and they introduce the data.
But problem what I have it is that they didn't introduce the data in to the database :).
So i want to know if there it is possible to put some message in to the code to know if the applicaction is arriving to that line in the code.

I was trying to put some code like this:

`new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Argh").setMessage("Works?").setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();`

But that code I can only put in "onCreate()", so there it is some code that I could put on every line of the app without giving me any error?

Thanks for any answer, Merry Christmas.

Comment: Log.i("YourApp", "Argh Works?"); Then check your Logcat to see it printed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into using the [Log class and Logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html).

Comment: Oh come on Jeff! Answer rudely stolen humbug :p

Comment: @Blundell: In my defense, your comment wasn't visible when I answered.  Great minds think alike?